# It is allowed to change the update() method frequency for PR2 controllers?

Tags: ros, pr2-controller-manager, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the parameters **/pr2_controller_manager/mechanism_statistics_publish_rate** and **/pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate**, but I didn't find anything that allows me to change the *update()* method frequency of a controller.

There is any way to modify this or the *update()* frequency is necessary 1000Hz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10042/it-is-allowed-to-change-the-update()-method-frequency-for-pr2-controllers?/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 controllers are design and tuned to operate at 1KHz, changing the update rate of the controller will significantly impact the stability of the controllers on the PR2. It is not recommended to change the update rate, you do so at your own risk.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in the pr2_ethercat package, look in main.cpp for:

period = 1e+6; // 1 ms in nanoseconds

but you shouldn't do this on a real PR2

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1